# Как извлечь текстовые данные в список?

Tags: python, строки, pandas, список, обработка-данных

Получаю данные таким способом:

```
def get_data(path):
    p = Path(path)
    train = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', index_col=0)
                       for f in p.glob('train_???.tsv*')],
                      ignore_index=True)
    test = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', index_col=0)
                      for f in p.glob('test_???.tsv*')],
                      ignore_index=True)
    return ((train['Text'], train['Sentiment']),
           (test['Text'], test['Sentiment']))

# read data=
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = get_data(r'C:\NLP1')
```

В итоге в `X_test` лежат данные в виде:

```
    0        As a zombie fan, I really love these types of ...
    1        After traveling around the world, it dawned on...
    2        Admittedly, I watched the MST3K version of thi...
    3        Not for everyone, but I really like it. Nice e...
    ...
   Name: Text, Length: 25000, dtype: object ...
```

Как мне извлечь текстовые данные в список в том же порядке, в котором  они лежат в данной структуре.

Comment: X_test.values.tolist()

Answer (score 2):

Наиболее идимоматичный способ преобразовать `pandas.Series` со строками в список строк - это воспользоваться методом [Series.to_list()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html):

```
In [19]: X.to_list()
Out[19]:
['As a zombie fan, I really love these types of',
 'After traveling around the world, it dawned on',
 'Admittedly, I watched the MST3K version of thi',
 'Not for everyone, but I really like it. Nice e']
```